# New car - soot on rims and slight burny smell

Tags: brakes, vw

Just purchased a 2016 VW Golf Sportwagen. Since I drove it off the lot I've noticed a slight burning smell coming from the wheels (assumed this was brakes), and this evening I noticed a lot of soot/fine black dust on the rims.  The car has about 200 km on it now. Is this normal? The internet gives me conflicting opinions.

Comment: Most likely the brakes breaking in, but I wouldn't be positive about it. No clue if this is normal or not with the new V-Dubs.

Answer (score 2):

The smell is certainly the brake pads bedding in, it's pretty normal. As is the brake dust - you can upgrade to lower dust pads, but you'll find that it's a common thing amongst nose-heavy cars with disc brakes.